# Context Menu that invokes other menus

Tags: android, contextmenu

I have a blank button on which I would like to assign a name, a color, and store a date--all when a user long-presses that button.  I would appreciate some guidance please.

1. Is starting with a ContextMenu the right thing to do?
2. From the ContextMenu, can I invoke other popup menus
       like an EditText view for the name, a date-picker for the date, and
       a color-picker for the color?

Any guidance on this kind of sub-menu invokation from a context menu is appreciated.  Or if I have the wrong philosophy for assigning a name, color, and date to a button, please suggest another technique.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the button long click all you will need to do is this

```
down.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
});
```

Then to create a context menu you will need to create a menu resource.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/new_game"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
      android:title="@string/new_game" />
<item android:id="@+id/help"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
      android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
```

Then in your activity override this method and inflate your context menu

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
 super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
 MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}
```

This is how you capture which item was selected and act accordingly to it

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
 switch (item.getItemId()) {
 case R.id.edit:
editNote(info.id);
return true;
case R.id.delete:
deleteNote(info.id);
return true;
default:
return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Now all you do is register your button for the context menu on long press like this..

```
registerForContextMenu(down);  //Your button
```

EDIT: To show a date picker just create a dialogDate picker and add

```
 showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
```

in the switch statement of the context menu..

Here is how you create a datepicker dialog

```
private TextView mDateDisplay;
private Button mPickDate;
private int mYear;
private int mMonth;
private int mDay;

static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
// get the current date
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

// the callback received when the user "sets" the date in the dialog
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                mYear = year;
                mMonth = monthOfYear;
                mDay = dayOfMonth;

            }
        };

@Override
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
switch (id) {
case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
    return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                mDateSetListener,
                mYear, mMonth, mDay);
}
return null;
```

}

Comment: Thanks @coder_For_Life22. Can you show some skeleton code on how one might invoke, say, a date-picker when one of the Context items are selected?

Comment: Great, thanks.  I'm not sure how this works, but if you think my question is a good one, kindly vote for it.